# Declaring string with apostrophe to be used in 'IN' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need someone's expertise in declaring strings with apostrophe (`'`) in it to be used in `WHERE` `IN` statement. Below is the sample of my current code which returns nothing:

```
DECLARE @Cons_Val VARCHAR(50) = '''Tot Mens'', ''Tot Womens'', ''Tot Kids'''

SELECT table1.column1 AS 'Country'
    , table1.column2 AS 'Consumer'
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column2 IN (@Cons_Val)
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Would need to use [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for this if insisting on using `IN` as so. Could also supply/use a derived table generation (easier from XML but that can be modified in). Could get away with a [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) but that loses any Sargable-ity on that column.

Comment: It's not your apostrophes, it's using a string literal as an array that's letting you down. In theory you could do it using dynamic SQL, but it seems a lot of faff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL if you want to variablize using IN statement.

```
DECLARE @Cons_Val VARCHAR(50) = '''Tot Mens'', ''Tot Womens'', ''Tot Kids'''

declare @sql varchar(1000) = 'SELECT table1.column1 AS Country
    , table1.column2 AS Consumer
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column2 IN (' + @Cons_Val + ')'

print @sql
exec (@sql)
```